# Swift: allow special characters

Tags: swift, special-characters

I am passing a NSURL string to a callback handler named oScheme

```
var oScheme = oScheme.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
```

It works great for encoding.

However, whenever a special character (é, in this case) appears, it crashes the app. How do I allow this special character?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSURL` object from the string and get the information you need using the appropriate properties like `scheme`, `host`, `path`, `query` for example

```
let URLString = "file:///Users/myUser/Documents/De%CC%81ja%CC%80%20Vue/"
let url = NSURL(string: URLString)

url?.path // /Users/myUser/Documents/Déjà Vue
url?.lastPathComponent // Déjà Vue
```

`NSURL` can handle the URL encoding / decoding automatically